# Random substitution has strange letter frequency

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, random

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{a,b\}$ be an alphabet, and define the random substitution
$$ \begin{align*}
\theta(a) &= \begin{cases}
aa & \text{with probability }p, \\
bb & \text{with probability }1-p,
\end{cases}\\
\theta(b) &= aa \qquad \text{with probability }1.
\end{align*}$$

The associated incidence matrix is then
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 2p & 2(1-p) \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

which is primitive and expanding. It has eigenvalues $2$ and $2(1-p)$ so the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue is $2$ and the Perron-Frobenius eigenvector, normalised to be a probability vector, is
$$\pi = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}.$$

This means that as $n \to \infty$, the proportion of $a$s in $\theta^n(a)$ tends to $\frac{1}{2}$, and same for $b$ (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11122 for a proof of this).

But this is clearly nonsense: the proportion of $a$s should be $p$. Set $p=0.99$ and do some trial runs on a computer and it should be clear that almost all of the letters after $n$ iterations are $a$, with the proportion tending towards 99%.

Where have I gone wrong?

My goal with this exercise was to try to find a random substitution whose incidence matrix depends on the probabilities but whose Perron-Frobenius eigenvector doesn't. I have succeeded with the substitution above, but the frequency as $n \to \infty$ just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt I never said it was a transition matrix. It's the incidence matrix: $M_{ij}$ = expected number of $a_j$ in $\theta(a_i)$.

Comment: What theorem from the linked paper are you using?

Comment: I think you are solving $M\pi=\lambda\pi$ when you should be solving $\pi'M=\lambda \pi'$.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt Prop 3.8. The result is known for deterministic substitutions (see Substitution Dynamical Systems - Spectral Analysis by Martine Queffélec, chapter 5) and the linked paper is showing the same result in the random case.

Comment: @kimchilover The theorem says we must use the right eigenvector, not the left. Edit: Ah, perhaps I have the incidence matrix transposed? That may be the problem, in which case yes the left eigenvector must be used.

Comment: I think you are using $M'$ instead of $M$.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, I have verified that transposing $M$ gives a more reasonable $\pi=(\frac{1}{2-p}, \frac{1-p}{2-p})$. Please add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a guess (I glanced at the paper but did not read it carefully: the pain/gain ratio seemed unfavorable) but it
seems likely that the matrix in question should be transposed, so "right" eigenvector appears where one might expect left eigenvector, and so on.